# Match a string until it meets a '('

Tags: c#, regex

I've managed to get everything (well, all letters) up to a whitespace using the following:

```
@"^.*([A-Z][a-z].*)]\s"
```

However, I want to to match to a `(` instead of a whitespace... how can I manage this?

Without having the '(' in the match

Comment: This would include the '('.. how can I manage without it?

Comment: Your current expression matches the whitespace too. Get the value of group 1 in both cases. Also, starting with `^.*` is pointless; just take that whole thing out.

Comment: From your description, I suspect `[A-Z][a-z].*` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you want is to match any character up until the `(` character, then this should work:

```
@"^.*?(?=\()"
```

If you want all letters, then this should do the trick:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z]*(?=\()"
```

Explanation:

```
^           Matches the beginning of the string

.*?         One or more of any character. The trailing ? means 'non-greedy', 
            which means the minimum characters that match, rather than the maximum

(?=         This means 'zero-width positive lookahead assertion'. That means that the 
            containing expression won't be included in the match.

\(          Escapes the ( character (since it has special meaning in regular 
            expressions)

)           Closes off the lookahead

[a-zA-Z]*?  Zero or more of any character from a to z, or from A to Z
```

Reference: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

**EDIT**: Actually, instead of using `.*?`, as Casimir has noted in his answer it's probably easier to use `[^\)]*`. The `^` used inside a character class (a character class is the `[...]` construct) inverts the meaning, so instead of "any of these characters", it means "any *except* these characters". So the expression using that construct would be:

```
@"^[^\(]*(?=\()"
```

Comment: this still includes the '(' in the match, any way to keep it out and match up till and without the '(' ?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. I've included a construct that should do what you want.

Comment: First one works perfectly, the second however does not give any matches

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: Just FYI, the non-greedy quantifier in `[a-zA-Z]*?` isn't doing anything useful.  Unlike `.*` or `.*?`, `[a-zA-Z]*` can't match `(`, so you don't need to sneak up on the match.

Comment: @AlanMoore great point! Answer edited. Not only that, since `[a-zA-Z]` can't match a `(` anyways, in practical use that expression wouldn't really be all that helpful, whereas the first one makes more sense.

Comment: Another +1 for the writeup/explanation - this is what makes a SO answer truly useful for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Using a constraining character class is the best way

```
@"^[^(]*"
```

`[^(]` means all characters but `(`

Note that you don't need a capture group since that you want is the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
([A-Z][a-z][^(]*)\(
```

The group will match a capital Latin letter, followed by a lower-case Latin letter, followed by any number of characters other than an open parenthesis. Note that `^.*` is not necessary.

Or this, which produces the same basic behavior but uses a [non-greedy quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) instead:

```
([A-Z][a-z].*?)\(
```